# Employee skills design and adding all rows of a table into another

Tags: database, database-design

I am trying to work out if my design is correct and how you query/insert onto it. A employee has a set of core competencies and job specific cmpetencies. A web site will ask for a scoring on their core competencies and then a set of specific competencies depending on their job type

I so far have a set of tables that represent employee, department (i.e. job type), competencies (core competencies, software competencies etc.)

Department:

```
Id
Department
```

Employee:

```
EmployeeId
LoginName
FK_DepartmentId
```

So each competency table would be something like this:

```
CompetencyId
Code
Description
```

The plan is that each person has core competencies and a corresponding job type and scores. My first thought is that the best way for the scores was to have a competency to score tables like this:

```
CompetencyScoreId 
EmployeeId_FK
CompetencyCode_FK
Score
```

I could then filter from the table using the person's id. By having multiple table scores I guess if someone changes department I just need to make sure they are removed from their old table and added to the new

When I add a new user I would then need to somehow paste the core table into the larger tables as a set of rows. Is this possible or sensible? Is it possible make a constraint such that username and code combinations are unique in the table?

The alternative was having a table where competency codes are columns and each user has a row in the table with scores against columns. I thought doing this makes it harder to add columns and I wasn't sure how you can associate column names to descriptions should I want to.

Comment: Are the competency scores for a person based their ability regardless of job, how their skills relate to a given position or both?

Comment: @ChrisSaxon All employees have a list of core competencies. A software engineer would have software competencies, a suystems engineer would have systems etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Department, Employee, and Competency tables are fine.

**Core Competency**

The Core Competency table should look like this

```
Core Competency
---------------
Core Competency ID
Employee ID
Competency ID
Competency Score
Competency Time Stamp
```

If the score can change over time, you need a time stamp so that you can maintain the score changes.

The primary (clustering) key is Core Competency ID

A unique index on Employee ID, Competency ID, and Competency Time Stamp descending would allow you to retrieve the rows for an employee.

Another unique index on Competency ID and Competency Time Stamp descending, would allow you to retrieve the rows for a competency and see how the scores change over time.

Another non-unique index on Competency ID and Competency Score descending would allow you to retrieve the employees with the highest competency scores for a given competency.

**Position Competency**

When a new employee is added, the core competencies will have to be added at the same time.  If you have a group of core competencies for a job position, you'll need another table that looks like this.

```
Position Competency
-------------------
Position Competency ID
Position ID
Competency ID
```

The primary (clustering) key is Position Competency ID.

The Position ID is a foreign key that points to a Position table.

A non-unique index on Position ID, Competency ID would give you all of the competencies for a position.

**Position Changes**

When an employee changes positions, the application should determine whether or not any core competencies need to be added.  The database tables I've defined would give the application the information necessary to make the determination.

Core competencies should never be removed from an employee.